# How to make UITableView show current item?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsdate

I have an array filled with dictionaries. 
Each dictionary have strings like title, info and date. 
Cells in the table are arranged by the date from the dictionary.

What should I do to make it show the cell as active if the date field in dictionary=current date or closest date in the future?

Thanks in advance! I'd really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to somehow highlight the current date. A simple thing would be to select the cell using `[cell setSelected:YES animated:YES]`. An other thing would be setting the `accessoryType` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` (`[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark]`). If you don't like these approaches, you can still create a custom UITableViewCell with support of some sort of highlighting, like showing an arrow in the cell.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. But you answered only a half of my qestion. Do u know how to set up a method which compares date in a dictionary with the curent date? Any suggestions about this? Thanks again

Comment: You might want to try this: [firstDate isEqualToDate:secondDate]; Look into the "NSDate Class Reference"